# override searchProvider.php does not work

Tags: prestashop

Create : override/modules/ps_facetedsearch/src/Product/SearchProvider.php

Create : override/modules/ps_facetedsearch/ps_facetedsearch.php

Delete the cache manually

Version : 1.7.6.4

override SearchProvider.php doesn't work

override ps_facetedsearch.php work

I need to delete 2 types of sorting ... into **SearchProvider.php:getAvailableSortOrders()** but I never go through the overloaded function

````
if (!defined('PS_VERSION'))
exit;

class SearchProviderOverride extends SearchProvider
{

/**
 * @return array
 */
public function getAvailableSortOrders()
{
    $sortPosAsc = new SortOrder('product', 'position', 'asc');
    $sortPriceAsc = new SortOrder('product', 'price', 'asc');
    $sortPriceDesc = new SortOrder('product', 'price', 'desc');
    $translator = $this->module->getTranslator();

    die('hello not world!');

    return [
        $sortPosAsc->setLabel(
            $translator->trans('Relevance', [], 'Modules.Facetedsearch.Shop')
        ),
        $sortPriceAsc->setLabel(
            $translator->trans('Price, low to high', [], 'Shop.Theme.Catalog')
        ),
        $sortPriceDesc->setLabel(
            $translator->trans('Price, high to low', [], 'Shop.Theme.Catalog')
        ),
    ];
}

}```
````

Answer (score 0):

"getAvailableSortOrders" is a private method. You are probably only hidding the private method with your public one.

You should override the "runQuery" method since it's the only one that uses "getAvailableSortOrders". This way your overriden "runQuery" will call the appropriate "getAvailableSortOrders" method.

And finally, you can make your "getAvailableSortOrders" private since its only meant  to be used in this class.

```php
if (!defined('PS_VERSION'))
exit;

class SearchProviderOverride extends SearchProvider
{

/**
 * @return array
 */
private function getAvailableSortOrders()
{
    $sortPosAsc = new SortOrder('product', 'position', 'asc');
    $sortPriceAsc = new SortOrder('product', 'price', 'asc');
    $sortPriceDesc = new SortOrder('product', 'price', 'desc');
    $translator = $this->module->getTranslator();

    die('hello not world!');

    return [
        $sortPosAsc->setLabel(
            $translator->trans('Relevance', [], 'Modules.Facetedsearch.Shop')
        ),
        $sortPriceAsc->setLabel(
            $translator->trans('Price, low to high', [], 'Shop.Theme.Catalog')
        ),
        $sortPriceDesc->setLabel(
            $translator->trans('Price, high to low', [], 'Shop.Theme.Catalog')
        ),
    ];
}

/**
 * @param ProductSearchContext $context
 * @param ProductSearchQuery $query
 *
 * @return ProductSearchResult
 */
public function runQuery(
    ProductSearchContext $context,
    ProductSearchQuery $query
) {
    $result = new ProductSearchResult();
    // extract the filter array from the Search query
    $facetedSearchFilters = $this->filtersConverter->createFacetedSearchFiltersFromQuery($query);

    $context = $this->module->getContext();
    $facetedSearch = new Search($context);
    // init the search with the initial population associated with the current filters
    $facetedSearch->initSearch($facetedSearchFilters);

    $orderBy = $query->getSortOrder()->toLegacyOrderBy(false);
    $orderWay = $query->getSortOrder()->toLegacyOrderWay();

    $filterProductSearch = new Filters\Products($facetedSearch);

    // get the product associated with the current filter
    $productsAndCount = $filterProductSearch->getProductByFilters(
        $query->getResultsPerPage(),
        $query->getPage(),
        $orderBy,
        $orderWay,
        $facetedSearchFilters
    );

    $result
        ->setProducts($productsAndCount['products'])
        ->setTotalProductsCount($productsAndCount['count'])
        ->setAvailableSortOrders($this->getAvailableSortOrders());

    // now get the filter blocks associated with the current search
    $filterBlockSearch = new Filters\Block(
        $facetedSearch->getSearchAdapter(),
        $context,
        $this->module->getDatabase()
    );

    $idShop = (int) $context->shop->id;
    $idLang = (int) $context->language->id;
    $idCurrency = (int) $context->currency->id;
    $idCountry = (int) $context->country->id;
    $idCategory = (int) $query->getIdCategory();

    $filterHash = md5(
        sprintf(
            '%d-%d-%d-%d-%d-%s',
            $idShop,
            $idCurrency,
            $idLang,
            $idCategory,
            $idCountry,
            serialize($facetedSearchFilters)
        )
    );

    $filterBlock = $filterBlockSearch->getFromCache($filterHash);
    if (empty($filterBlock)) {
        $filterBlock = $filterBlockSearch->getFilterBlock($productsAndCount['count'], $facetedSearchFilters);
        $filterBlockSearch->insertIntoCache($filterHash, $filterBlock);
    }

    $facets = $this->filtersConverter->getFacetsFromFilterBlocks(
        $filterBlock['filters']
    );

    $this->labelRangeFilters($facets);
    $this->addEncodedFacetsToFilters($facets);
    $this->hideUselessFacets($facets, (int) $result->getTotalProductsCount());

    $facetCollection = new FacetCollection();
    $nextMenu = $facetCollection->setFacets($facets);
    $result->setFacetCollection($nextMenu);
    $result->setEncodedFacets($this->facetsSerializer->serialize($facets));

    return $result;
}

}
```

Comment: thank you for your information despite everything at first it seems to me that the overload is not taken into account I never manage to produce a dump "hello world" in the class SearchProviderOverride despite the removal of the cache and the activation / deactivation of the original module

Comment: I don't know where to look for debugging, this is my problem ...

Comment: maybe i will have to use an alternative but for the moment i don't want to

Comment: You must be more specific about what you did. Did you try to also override the "runQuery" method ? You are not overloading here, you are overriding and it seems like you don't really understand what it implies. I'm about to edit my answer with a full code example.